# what is the best way to use two extension file into loop for a job in bash script?

Tags: bash, sh

how could you deal with two files at a time with different extension. More importantly, one such as file.fa is affiliated with file.qv and need to process at the same time.

Issue: suppose you dont know what is the name of file (basename) and number of files (might be fewer to hundreds ), just we know file extension of both files.

I tried with:

```
for i in `ls -1 -v $input_reads_dir/reads/*.csfasta $input_reads_dir/reads/*.qual` ;do
    job -o /out{i} {i}.fa {i}.qv
done
```

Problems:

1. Its does not work
2. I have fear that it could be mislead with `file1.csfasta` with `file2.qual` which is not correct or I should not be fear.

Comment: [Don't parse the output from ls.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLshttp://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: I am calling ls bcz i wanted to be sure that i am working on same files like A.csfasta A.qual and want to produce output from it.

Comment: That's not a reason to parse `ls` output. Don't do that. Use a glob like in Ignacio's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if the corresponding file exists first.

```
for f in *.csfasta
do
  if [ -f "${f%.csfasta}.qual" ]
  then
    dosomething "$f" "${f%.csfasta}.qual"
  fi
done
```

Comment: It does not work for me :( However, i checked file existence already before in my script so, i dont think so its necessary.
 (nothing happened, just tools showed his input arguments)

for f in $input_reads_dir/reads/*.csfasta
do
    solid2fastq -o $output_dir/before_qc/$f "${f%.csfasta}.qual"
done

Comment: @unique379 `$f` is the full path to the file in your snippet. You will need to use `basename` or similar to get down to the bare filename if you want to stick an output path on to it.